# Calculating quantile when a condition is met

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas.

My DataFrame looks like this:

[image: DataFrame]

I am having problems with adding 1st, 2nd, 3rd quartiles to my DataFrame.

I am trying to get quartiles for column `CTR` if they are on the same group determined by column `Cat`.

In total, I have about 40 groups.

What I've tried:

```
df_final['1st quartile'] = round(
    df_final.groupby('Cat')['CTR'].quantile(0.25), 2)
df_final['2nd quartile'] = round(
    df_final.groupby('Cat')['CTR'].quantile(0.5), 2)
df_final['3rd quartile'] = round(
    df_final.groupby('Cat')['CTR'].quantile(0.75), 2)
```

But values get added in a way I cannot explain, like starting in second row and rather than being added the way as last column `CTR Average Difference vs category`.

My desired output would look the same as the last column, `CTR Average Difference vs category`, one line per category.

Any suggestions what might be wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Please share your `df` as text not as image.

Comment: Hi, @rpanai, I always do, this time it seemed like it was not necessary. As the image explains the problem and does not require to be copy-pasted to test it.

Answer (score 1):

If want new column filled by aggregated values like `mean`, `sum` or quantile use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
#similar ofr 2. and 3rd quantile
df_final['1st quartile'] = (df_final.groupby('Cat')['CTR']
                                    .transform(lambda x: x.quantile(0.25))
                                    .round(2))
```

Or you can use [`DataFrameGroupBy.quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.quantile.html) and then [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) by `Cat` column:

```
df = df_final.groupby('Cat')['CTR'].quantile([0.2, 0.5, 0.75]).round(2)
df.columns = ['1st quartile','2nd quartile','3rd quartile']
df_final = df_final.join(df, on='Cat')
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael, do you know why my method produced the output in the image? I mean what logical reason is there to start writing information in the second row?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - hmmm, it is weird, not idea